# Pythonで生成したdataframeを呼び出したい

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Tkinterにより読み込んだ複数のファイルをそれぞれ（i番目の）Dataframeに格納するプログラムを作成したのですが、それぞれのDataframeにアクセスする方法が知りたいです。

例えば `print(i番目のDataframe)` などの動作を想定しております。`i` 番目のDataframeを宣言する方法を教えてください。

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
#複数ファイル読み込み　
root=tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

fTyp=[('テキストファイルとExcelファイル','*.txt;*.csv')] 

iDir=''
i = 0
filenames=tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=fTyp,initialdir=iDir)
for f in filenames:
     df_amp = pd.read_csv(f,header=None,delimiter=',',skiprows=37)
     exec(f"df_amp{i} = pd.DataFrame(df_amp)")

   i=+1
```

Comment: `print(df_amp0)`で1つ目のDataFrameが、`print(df_amp1)`で2つ目のDataFrameが表示されると思いますが、質問はそういう意味ではないですか？

Comment: Dataframeの配列を定義して、そこにファイルから読み込んだデータを持つDataframeに入れておく。
そうすれば、データフレームの配列のインデックスを i にすると、i番目のDataframeが得られます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。df_amp0, df_amp1等と宣言すれば表示されることは承知しておりました。ただ、毎回開くファイル数が異なるため変数iを用いて呼びたしたい状況です。

Comment: i(読み込んだファイルの個数・毎回変わる)のDataframe配列を生成する方法がございましたらお知らせ頂けないでしょうか。